# Prevent the user from moving to the next form

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a `Form` with a `TextBox`. I would like to prevent the user from moving on to the next form without filling in the black `TextBox`. How can I do that?

```
if(textBox.Text.Length == 0)
    MessageBox.Show("Have To Fill All The Fields!");
```

What more should I add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add handler to `Validating` event and use error provider to set validation error to control:

```
void textBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) 
{
  string error = null;
  if(textBox.Text.Length == 0 ) {
    error = "Please enter this value";
    e.Cancel = true;
  }
  errorProvider1.SetError((Control)sender, error);
}
```

You can use same handler for several textbox controls (just use sender from event arguments to get particular textbox instance).

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Form_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill the field");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What else you want?
The code would be something like that for moving on next form

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(textBox.Text.Length == 0)
     {
          MessageBox.Show("Have To Fill All The Fields!");
          textBox.focus();
     }
     else
     {
          // Work to move on next form
     }
}
```